# Couchbase lite Android document status

Tags: android, couchbase

I am developing an android application using couchbase lite v1.1 with a push and pull replication on a remote couchbase server.

I would like to know if there is a way to know if a document has been pushed on the server database or not without asking to the server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on github issues. The functionality was implemented on java-core which is used by couchbase-lite-android as the core library.

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-java-core/commit/8798881e3fb2e889e3e1944ef31ebd5329b0ea73